# Android Filtered list item not removing after click

Tags: android, listview, searchview, custom-adapter, android-filterable

I have a custom adapter extends Base adapter and implements Filterable. When i write something to searchview filter is working well. Before filtering when i click the list item of listview, it is removed successfully. But after filtering when i click the list item, its not removing . How can i fix this problem ?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOMBl.png)    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOMBl.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D44F5.png)    [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D44F5.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx72O.png)    [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx72O.png)

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utJrH.png)    [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utJrH.png)

adapter:

```
public class kisiler_adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

private Context mContext;
private List<kisiler> kisilerList;
private List<kisiler> filteredList;

private CustomFilter filter;
private ArrayList<kisiler> filters;


public kisiler_adapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<kisiler> kisilerList) {
    this.mContext=context;
    this.kisilerList=kisilerList;
    this.filteredList=kisilerList;
}

public void update(ArrayList<kisiler> results){
    kisilerList=new ArrayList<>();
    kisilerList.addAll(results);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView isim_tv;
    TextView numara_tv;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return kisilerList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return kisilerList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder ;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_kisiler_dialog_listview,parent,false);

        holder=new ViewHolder();

        holder.isim_tv=convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_kisiler_isim_dialog);
        holder.numara_tv=convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_kisiler_numara_dialog);
        // store the holder with the view
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    kisiler veri=kisilerList.get(position);

    holder.isim_tv.setText(veri.getIsim());
    holder.numara_tv.setText(veri.getNumara());



    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(filter == null)
    {
        filter=new CustomFilter();
    }

    return filter;
}


class CustomFilter extends Filter{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();
        if(constraint!=null &&constraint.length()>0){
            constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            filters=new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i=0;i<filteredList.size();i++){
                if(filteredList.get(i).getIsim().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                    kisiler k=new kisiler(filteredList.get(i).getIsim(),filteredList.get(i).getNumara());
                    filters.add(k);
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(mContext,String.valueOf(filters.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            filterResults.count=filters.size();
            filterResults.values=filters;



        }else {
            filterResults.count=filteredList.size();
            filterResults.values=filteredList;
        }
        return filterResults;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        kisilerList=(ArrayList<kisiler>)filterResults.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

search view :

```
//search view
void searchMethod(){

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search person...");  //search view
    gridLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(list!=null &&list.size()>0){
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                circleImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                circleImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

search methods:

```
    @Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    return false;
}
```

and list view clisk events:

```
    public void listview_click(){

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            gridLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            kisiler kisi=(kisiler)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),kisi.getIsim(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            grid_list.add(kisi);
            list.remove(kisi);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            if(list!=null &&list.size()>0){
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                circleImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                circleImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if(grid_list!=null && grid_list.size()>0){
                gridLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                DynamicViews dynamicViews=new DynamicViews(getActivity());
                TextView textView=dynamicViews.isim_text_view(getContext(),kisi.getIsim(),kisi.getNumara());
                CircleImageView button=dynamicViews.iptal_buttonu(getContext());

                gridLayout.addView(dynamicViews.linearLayout(getActivity(),textView,button),0);


                if(grid_list!=null&&grid_list.size()>0&&gridLayout.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                    for( int i=0;i<gridLayout.getChildCount();i++){
                        final LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
                        final kisiler kisi2=grid_list.get(grid_list.size()-1-i);

                        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                gridLayout.removeView(linearLayout);
                                list.add(kisi2);
                                grid_list.remove(kisi2);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                alfabetik_siralama();

                                if(list!=null &&list.size()>0){
                                    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    circleImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }else {
                                    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    circleImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            }else {
                gridLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }



        }
    });



}
```